# Is solana_sdk wasm incompatible with @solana/web3.js?

Tags: web3.js, rust, javascript, solana-sdk

I'm trying to create a rust wasm crate that takes a [TransactionInstruction](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/TransactionInstruction.html) from js, mutates it, and return it.

I'm trying to use [serde-wasm-bindgen](https://crates.io/crates/serde-wasm-bindgen) to handle the js-wasm interop.

As a test, I have this test wasm function that just takes a `TransactionInstruction`, deserializes it and then serializes and returns it:

```
use solana_sdk::instruction::Instruction;
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn return_ix(ix: JsValue) -> Result<JsValue, JsValue> {
    let deser: Instruction = serde_wasm_bindgen::from_value(ix)?;
    Ok(serde_wasm_bindgen::to_value(&deser)?)
}
```

Testing this out on a simple web app with the following js:

```
import { Keypair, SystemProgram } from "@solana/web3.js";
import * as wasmTest from "wasm-test";

const IX = SystemProgram.createAccount({
  fromPubkey: Keypair.generate().publicKey,
  newAccountPubkey: Keypair.generate().publicKey,
  lamports: 1,
  space: 0,
  programId: Keypair.generate().publicKey,
})

console.log(IX);
const RET = wasmTest.return_ix(IX);
console.log(RET);
```

However, this throws `Uncaught Error: missing field program_id`, presumably because the `TransactionInstruction` object has the field in camelCase `programId` instead of snake_case `program_id`

Wondering if there's a way to make these 2 libraries work together without rewriting the solana_sdk structs to have `#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]`

Comment: As you've noticed, the WASM and JS worlds are currently separated, so they're not meant to interoperate. Feel free to hack on the monorepo and see if you can get things to work though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [kaizen project](https://github.com/solana-kaizen) has implemented rust bindings for `@solana/web3.js` in the [solana-web3-sys crate](https://github.com/solana-kaizen/solana-web3-sys), with `TryFrom` implemented between the `solana-program` rust types and `@solana/web3.js` js types